# React CSS: trying to give Color to class for a few seconds when there is a change on state vs prevState

Tags: css, reactjs

Goal: I want to compare prevState with actualState to display a different class on a `<div>` depending on the comparision.

Problem: When the iteration results in no switch of class,i cant see the difference since the className doesnt trigger the keyframe event.

JSX:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import styles from "./CoinContainer.module.css";

function usePrevious(data) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = data;
  }, [data]);
  return ref.current;
}
export default function CoinContainer({ coin, price }) {
  const [priceUpdated, setPrice] = useState("");
  const prevPrice = usePrevious(priceUpdated);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(priceUpdate, 20000);
  });

  const toggleClassName = () => {
    return prevPrice > priceUpdated ? styles.redPrice : styles.greenPrice;
  };

  function priceUpdate() {
    return fetch(
      `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${coin}&vs_currencies=usd`
    )
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((result) => {
        let key = Object.keys(result);
        setPrice(result[key].usd);
      });
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.padding}>
      <h2>{coin}</h2>
      <h3 className={toggleClassName()}>
        {priceUpdated ? priceUpdated : price}$
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes upFadeBetween {
  from {
    color: green;
  }
  to {
    color: white;
  }
}

@keyframes downFadeBetween {
  from {
    color: red;
  }
  to {
    color: white;
  }
}

.redPrice {
  color: white;
  animation: downFadeBetween 5s;
}

.greenPrice {
  color: white;
  animation: upFadeBetween 5s;
}
```

Thanks so much for any feedback/help!

Comment: I cant see patterns when it doesnt works unfortunaly. Overall it adds the className 50% or so. The more time i let the app run,the less it works it seems tho.

Comment: Ok i got the pattern now i think. When the iteration is styles.redPrice - styles.redPrice and viceverse with greenPrice, i see no difference because my CSS is bad.
I do happen to see the difference when there is switch. Here is my CSS just in case anyone know how to solve it: